# Reading a switch without a pull-up/pull-down resistor, for input into a script

Tags: resistors, switches, pullup, pulldown, sbc

The standard way to read a switch seems to be using a pull up/down resistor. I don't have one handy (I'm doing a one-off Raspberry Pi project while travelling and don't want to buy 100 resistors) - is there any reason not to just connect one end of the switch to power and the other end to my ADC input? It seems to work: when switch is connected I get 3.3V, when switch is disconnected I get a randomly fluctuating value that seems to always be significantly less than 3.3V (never seen it go over 1.5V). This is perfectly sufficient information for the Python script that will be receiving this input.

(If I wire one end to ground, that doesn't work. The voltage reading is 0V when connected of course, but when disconnected fluctuates randomly with values sometimes reaching 0V.)

Any reason not to do this? This is a non-mission-critical project powered by wall power. The switch is a momentary push SPST-NO switch. I'm using an ADC chip (MCP3008) with a Raspberry Pi (I could connect the switch directly to the Pi but the wiring is a little cleaner if I use the ADC).

Comment: does the rpi not have internal pullup resistors you can turn on? Most microcontrollers do, but I'm not familiar with the ARM processors that the pi uses.

Comment: (1) I vaguely remember that if you set a Rpi GPIO pin to input mode, you could at the same time enable the pin's internal pullup. (2) Most input of I2C/SPI ADCs modules have pullups already soldered on. I usually need to desolder those pullups because too many pull ups overload the Rpi GPIO pin.

Comment: enable the internal pullup or pulldown resistors ... why did you not post this question at https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions or at least done some research?

Comment: @jsotola this question is equally applicable to an arduino or any setup where you're reading a switch in code. I did do some research but every search query I came up with was filled with results about using pull up/down resistors, as opposed to making do without them. I wanted to know from an electronics perspective what possible pitfalls or downsides there are to not using one, and the answers have been helpful so far.

Comment: @tobek You don't need to buy any resistors as you can simply enable the internal pull-ups. You don't need external resistors. Same applies to Arduino and Rpi. And downside of not using a pull-up at all is that in the released state nothing defines the input pin state decisively, as then the input pin would be floating, and pin state would be indeterminate.

Answer (score 2):

Without a resistor, when the switch is open, your line acts as an Antenna and can get random fluctuation.

Is your implementation good and reliable? Probably not.

The raspberry does have internal pullups, that you can use, check this [forum](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=202568).

And get some resistors sets with different values, it's cheap and they will come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, a switch would be read by a digital input, and a pull-up or pull-down resistor is needed to ensure that the input receives a valid logic level when the switch is open.

Since you are using an ADC input, if you are satified that the ADC can reliably distinguish between switch-open and switch-closed condition, you could do without the resistor - but should be willing to tolerate the ADC occasionally indicating the switch is closed when it is not.

Answer (score 1):

While other answers have addressed the fact that the Raspberry Pi does have pull-ups and there are better alternatives to what is suggested, I will recount a technique I have used in a case where no pull-up/pull-down was available.

In a project using a PIC16F1455, I naively assumed that all pins had programmable WPU (weak pull up), when some did and some did not. To avoid modifying the PCB design, I preceded the pin read by a brief (83ns on the 12MHz instruction clock) high pulse on the IO pin.

When the switch was open, the pin read high due to the small amount of stray capacitance in the circuit. When the switch was closed, the pin read low, as expected. I guess the stray inductance of the circuit also helps to reduce the peak current through the pin driver.

In my case, some thorough testing showed correct switch detection and no sign of the pin driver being damaged. Of course, this may not work in all scenarios and may cause damage in others.

But for cases where there is no way to add an internal or external pull-up, it may work under some conditions.